# Batch upsert multiple rows with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to upsert (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`) multiple rows at once into a postgreSQL database using psycopg2. Essentially, I have a list of tuples representing "rows", and I need to insert them into the database, or update the database if there is a conflict. I need (possibly) every column to be updated (if not inserted), along with every row.

I've tried two main approaches, using psycopg2's `cursor.execute()` function and `execute_many()` function. First, I did the following:

```
upsert_statement = 'INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES %s ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE SET (col1, col2, col3) = ROW (excluded.*) WHERE table IS DISTINCT FROM excluded'

psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, upsert_statement, values)
```

I create an SQL statement that inserts the values using `execute_many()` (where `values` passed to it is a list of tuples), and on a conflict the column values should be updated to excluded. However, I get the error `SyntaxError: number of columns does not match number of values` *sometimes*, even though I know for a *fact* that the number of columns and values are the same.

So, I tried using only `execute()`:

```
upsert_statement = f'INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3), (value4, value5, value6)... ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE SET (col1, col2, col3) = (value1, value2, value3), (value4, value5, value6)...'

cursor.execute(upsert_statement)
```

Here, I do the batch upsert as part of the SQL, and so don't have to use `execute_values()`. However, I get a `SyntaxError` after the `DO UPDATE SET`, because I don't think it's valid to have `(col1, col2, col3) = (value1, value2, value3), (value4, value5, value6)...`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I bulk upsert multiple rows using psycopg2?

(I should note that in reality, `(col1, col2, col3)` and `(value1, value2, value3)` are dynamic, and change frequently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [table `EXCLUDED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) instead of value literals in your `ON CONFLICT` statement:

> The `SET` and `WHERE` clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to the row proposed for insertion using the special **`excluded`** table.

You also don't need to re-set the conflicting values, only the rest.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES 
    (value1, value2, value3), 
    (value4, value5, value6)
ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE 
SET (col2, col3) = (EXCLUDED.col2, EXCLUDED.col3);
```

For readability, you can format your in-line SQLs if you triple-quote your f-strings. I'm not sure if and which IDEs can detect it's an in-line SQL in Python and switch syntax highlighting, but I find indentation helpful enough.

```
upsert_statement = f"""
    INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) 
    VALUES 
        ({value1}, {value2}, {value3}), 
        ({value4}, {value5}, {value6})
    ON CONFLICT (col1) DO UPDATE 
    SET (col2, col3) = (EXCLUDED.col2, EXCLUDED.col3)"""
```

Here's a [test at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rB5SeFFV):

```sql
drop table if exists test_70066823 cascade;
create table test_70066823 (
    id integer primary key, 
    text_column_1 text, 
    text_column_2 text);
insert into test_70066823 values
  (1,'first','first')
 ,(2,'second','second') returning *;
```

| id | text_column_1 | text_column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | first |
| 2 | second | second |

```sql
insert into test_70066823
values  (1, 'third','first'),
        (3, 'fourth','third'),
        (4, 'fifth','fourth'),
        (2, 'sixth','second')
on conflict (id) do update 
set text_column_1=EXCLUDED.text_column_1,
    text_column_2=EXCLUDED.text_column_2
returning *;
```

| id | text_column_1 | text_column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | third | first |
| 3 | fourth | third |
| 4 | fifth | fourth |
| 2 | sixth | second |

You can refer to [this](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#results-summary) for improved insert performance. Inserts with a simple string-based `execute` or `execute_many` are the top 2 slowest approaches mentioned there.